# Embedded (ASP.NET) web server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, automated-tests, embeddedwebserver

I am looking for a light-web embeddable web server for .NET.

I need it to fake a SOAP web-service for automated testing, so it is a big plus if it supports ASP.NET web-services or another easy way to create SOAP web-services. Extra bonus points for quick startup and shutdown and multiple simultaneous instances on different ports.

A Google search turns up [aspnetserve](http://code.google.com/p/aspnetserve/), [www-Sharp.Runtime](http://www-sharp.com/) and [Neokernel Web Server](http://www.neokernel.com/content.agent?page_name=Home). Do anyone have any experience with those or other solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the [Cassini Web Server](https://code.google.com/p/cassini/).

---

<sup><sup>Edit</sup></sup>
And now 6 1/2 years later, I'd recommend [IIS Express](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview) instead.

Comment: Ah, I had heard about Cassini, but did not know that it was embeddable. Thanks.

Comment: Cassini link is 404.  Try the options listed by Matthew Lock

Comment: the page has been deleted

Comment: Fixed again. This answer is old now, though. Today I'd recommend IIS Express, instead.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [XSP web server](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET) that is bundled with mono.

Answer (score 2):

Some others I recently came across that can host ASP.NET

- [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)
- [UltiDev Cassini](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/)
- [Abyss Web Server](http://www.aprelium.com/)
- [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Could not find any information that suggests IIS Express was embeddable.  Out of this list CassiniDev looks the most promising and up to date.