# What engine to use for creating .net 2 c# application based on HTML layout?

Tags: c#, html, .net-2.0

I'm browsing the net now for days, but still couldn't find what I'm looking for. Basically I'd like to develop my application interface, the GUI using HTML and CSS, with of course keeping the events, and the chance to modify parts of the layout at runtime (like a content of a div). The application is a database manager displaying visually the datas, and updating them at runtime.

- **IE** aka using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser, this is what I try to avoid, it depends on the client system, stops at version 7, hard to link with the application
- **HTMLayout** - http://www.terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/ : seems interesting, but the .net c# part, the nabu-library is dead
- **Sciter** - http://www.terrainformatica.com/sciter/ : from the same group as HTMLayout, but couldn't really understand the integration, and I'm not sure if this is what I want - also couldn't find .net c# infos
- **Awesomium** - http://awesomium.com/ : which really seems nice at first, but it needs .net 4 , and we have to stay at .net 2 - also it seems too much to handle, to use, and .net wiki is a little weak: http://wiki.awesomium.net/
- and finally **Gecko** http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/ and **Webkit** http://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/ - but currently I'm not sure that they can be used to render the whole application, they just seem to be a WebBrowser with another engine.

Did I miss something?

Comment: From your concerns about Gecko and Webkit I could tell that you need embedded web server. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/462444/551322).

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be too much for me. I use SQLite for database, I only need HTML/CSS display for dynamic, stylish and flexible display.

Comment: FYI - you can change the WebBrowser control to use IE9 as long as you have it installed on your machine. You can do this via this line in your HTML head: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" > or through the registry, see this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control. I recently did this for a project and it worked, but - I also hate IE ;) But if you're writing a .NET application, at least you know IE has guaranteed support and fewer glitches. I've had issues developing in Chrome w/Visual Studio.

Comment: Why do you need to stay in .net2? We live in the year 2013!

Comment: Thanks Marco, but the users choose what they use, and I as a developer have to satisfy their needs without checking the calendar. If they use XP I have to code for XP, it is not the developers job to change the users.

Comment: ZTefter - Please check this one .. Ext.NET Framework, Awesome frameworK. If you want I will give u samples. http://www.ext.net/download/

Comment: Thank you, it seems quite nice, but unfortunately it needs ".NET 3.5, 4.0* and 4.5", and because of my users I have to stick with .NET2

Comment: FYI, .NET 3.5 is just .NET 2.0 SP2 with additional assemblies

Answer (score 1):

[Sciter integration principles](http://terrainformatica.com/sciter/sciter-basics.whtm) are outlined [here](http://www.terrainformatica.com/2012/11/sciter-ui-application-architecture/) and [here](http://www.terrainformatica.com/2013/04/calling-code-behind-ui-from-worker-threads/).

Sciter and HTMLayout both use the same integration principles and API architecture.

As of .NET wrapper, check these projects:

1. https://github.com/midiway/SciterSharp
2. https://code.google.com/p/expemerent/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits your requirements but I currently use Webkit.NET http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Essentially I use its Webkit Browser Control for the interface, store the HTML/CSS markup as variables and then I use C# to perform server-side logic, then output the results to the Browser Control (C# in this case acting in place of PHP since I am not including a portable web server with my application).

I did want to update it to achieve some newer functionality/standards so this article was most helpful.

http://peterdn.com/post/(First!)-Using-WebKit-nightly-builds-with-WebKit-NET.aspx